# Pandas Dataframe from a text file (table) python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Considering my text file would have the following pattern:

```
    CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       NAMES
    xxxxxxxxxxxx   yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy                                                  zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    bbbbbbbbbbb                  ports                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       random name
```

Basically the output of **docker ps** command, written to a text file. What is the most effective way to convert this into a data frame or a readable format into python, to query the values. (i.e.) Given a name, get the matching container ID etc.

I tried

```
    df = pd.read_csv("docker.txt",sep="  ")
```

but there are lapses, as the delimiter is not consistent.

Comment: use regular expressions to handle the inconsistent delimiters

Comment: Does `sep='\s+'` work for you?

Comment: `pd.read_csv("docker.txt", sep='\s{2,}')`

Comment: @PandaKim does the job yes, but misses out any empty values for the columns. the next value is taken

Comment: `df = pd.read_fwf('docker.txt')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

column_names = ["CONTAINER ID", "IMAGE", "COMMAND", "CREATED", "STATUS", "PORTS", "NAMES"]


data = []
with open("docker.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines[1:]]

    for line in lines:
        values = re.split(r'\s{2,}', line)
        data.append(values)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_names)

print(df)
```

[image]

Hope this helps with using regex and getting dataframe from text file

Comment: thank you for the answer. there are actually 7 columns, from the output of docker ps, if you can use the scroll bar

Comment: Its just add the column names, I just updated the script and output